# Loop TimerEvents?

Tags: arrays, loops, timer, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a script that makes my instances of a movieclip on stage (bal1, bal2, bal3, bal4, bal5, bal6) invisible and then turn them visible one by one, each one appearing on stage faster than the previous one. I've created a script using TimerEvents to achieve this, but it's very long and there probably has to be a way to make this shorter:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var mySpheres:Array = [bal1, bal2, bal3, bal4, bal5, bal6];

for (var i:Number = 0; i < mySpheres.length; i++) {
    mySpheres[i].visible = false;
}

var myTimer1:Timer = new Timer(1024,1);
var myTimer2:Timer = new Timer(512,1);
var myTimer3:Timer = new Timer(256,1);
var myTimer4:Timer = new Timer(128,1);
var myTimer5:Timer = new Timer(64,1);
var myTimer6:Timer = new Timer(32,1);

myTimer1.start();

//number 1

myTimer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock1);
function tickTock1(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal1.visible = true;
}

myTimer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext1);
function startNext1(e:TimerEvent):void {
    myTimer2.start();
}

//number 2

myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock2);
function tickTock2(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal2.visible = true;
}

myTimer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext2);
function startNext2(e:TimerEvent):void {
    myTimer3.start();
}

//number 3

myTimer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock3);
function tickTock3(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal3.visible = true;
}

myTimer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext3);
function startNext3(e:TimerEvent):void {
    myTimer4.start();
}

//number 4

myTimer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock4);
function tickTock4(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal4.visible = true;
}

myTimer4.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext4);
function startNext4(e:TimerEvent):void {
    myTimer5.start();
}

//number 5

myTimer5.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock5);
function tickTock5(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal5.visible = true;
}

myTimer5.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext5);
function startNext5(e:TimerEvent):void {
    myTimer6.start();
}

//number 6

myTimer6.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock6);
function tickTock6(e:TimerEvent):void {
    bal6.visible = true;
}

myTimer6.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startNext6);
function startNext6(e:TimerEvent):void {
    stop();
}
```

I've tried using for loops, but I can't get them to work. This is the furthest I got, but it doesn't work:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var mySpheres:Array = [bal1, bal2, bal3, bal4, bal5, bal6];
var myTimers:Array = new Array;

for (var j:Number = 0; j < mySpheres.length; j++) {
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1024, 1);
    myTimers.push(myTimer);
}

for (var k:Number = 0; k < mySpheres.length; k++) {
    myTimers[k].start();
    myTimers[k].addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
    function tick(e:TimerEvent):void {
        mySpheres[k].visible = true;
    }
}
```

Notice also in this last example I don't know how to create a variable delay for the different myTimer variables (here, all timers are set to a delay of 1024ms).
Does anyone have an idea to make this work?
If possible, it would also be very helpful if I could manipulate the intervals at which the next instances appear by use of a variable, that changes its value, according to its previous value. What I mean by this is that in the first (working) example I gave, I have manually set all the timer delays as half of the previous timer (1024, 512, 256, et cet.). So basically: delay(new) = delay(previous) * 0,5. I wonder if I can change this 0,5 to whatever I want.